# Poliigon textures reflection map with PBR

Tags: cycles-render-engine, pbr

At the moment Im using Blender 2.78. Im using Blender Guru's PBR Workaround for materials. In the scene I'm working on I use textures from Poliigon.com. In the Poliigon help guide it says that reflection maps should **not** be used in a PBR workflow. So that socket will have no node connected to it. Is it then up to me to estimate the reflection value for the material? That doesn't feel right.

[image]

Comment: What does a "*reflection map" mean? Do they mean an Environment Map or a Specularity map? If it is the former it makes sense, and a specularity or reflection map would take care of the reflection amount, otherwise something would indeed be missing.

Comment: Imho you should direct this at Poliigon support how to use their textures. It is paid so they should assist their customers. Their statement that reflection map in PBR workflow should not be used is wrong. It can be, but has very little effect and usually is omitted, because dielectric materials have very similar reflection values (and very low).

Answer (score 1):

This is how Andrew Price set up his wooden floor.

[image]

After some digging I came to the conclusion that this value should be left at 0 in this case.